# How to disable the new element picker in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, blocking, ublock-origin

Recently when pressing <kbd>Alt + Z</kbd> in Firefox an element picker show up. If I click on it the element is temporarily hidden, until the page is reloaded:

[image]

This has never happened to me before. This new feature isn't listed in the [Release Note for Firefox 54](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/54.0/releasenotes/) or [its sister page for web developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/54). It is different to the element picker from uBlock Origin addon:

[image]

What is this, and how to disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from uBlock Origin. Fixed in 1.13.4, see [Release notes](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/releases/tag/1.13.4).